# Draw a datatable when document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there a way to automatically dra a datatable, after document.ready?
It means, draw the datatable without make an action such as changing the sorting, filtering or paging?
This how actually I'm doing it, but it just works util I make one of the actions mentioned, and I need to do it whithouth that action. **It is possible?**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


           var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

            // Event listener for DT 1.10+
            table.on('draw', function() {
                $(".auditButton.Submitted").removeClass('btn-outline-primary');
                $(".auditButton.Submitted").addClass('btn-outline-success');
                $(".auditButton.Expired").addClass('btn-outline-danger');
                $(".auditButton.Capturable").addClass('btn-outline-warning');
            });
        });
```

**Using body.onload**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('load','body *',function(){
                $(".auditButton.Submitted").removeClass('btn-outline-primary');
                $(".auditButton.Submitted").addClass('btn-outline-success');
                $(".auditButton.Expired").addClass('btn-outline-danger');
                $(".auditButton.Capturable").addClass('btn-outline-warning');
                });
            });
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're going for, but if you're trying to trigger the functions inside table.on('draw'). I would just add those into the initComplete callback for datatables. https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

Comment: _it just works_ - is that a typo? It implies that it's doing what you are asking, so a bit confusing.  Also, please see [ask], and creating an [mcve]

Comment: You have two question; 1. You want the data-table to be drawn when the document is ready and 2. you want the datatable to display with no sorting, grouping etc.  Both of these are already answered on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. At the moment of the load body.

```
body.onload = function(){myScript};
```

or onload on other object:

```
object.onload = function(){myScript};
```

Comment: No it should not be inside the document.ready because it's not jQuery but native JS

Comment: `$(document).on('load','body *',function(){yourScript});});`

Comment: I've edited my question with the answer you gave me, but it does not works, and it does not display any error, could you check if mys script is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I gave you an example, I let you adapt it.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#test').text('Insert text after on load webpage!');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/NicolasLsn/whvoa7yg/14/